# Backup ACCESS Database using PHP script

Tags: php, ms-access, database-backups

Is it possible to back up an `access database`? I have done research on how to backup access database through php but I wasnt able to get a good answer. Most of the result that came out is about backing up `MySQL database`. Can anyone help me :) thanks

Comment: "access database", as in *Microsoft Access*? If so, then are Access databases not just normal files, just like SQLite databases?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - yes! `microsoft access`. The Database contains information about employees :)

Comment: Backup as in [copy()](http://php.net/copy)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - yeah! i want to automatically back it up

Comment: I mean, is it possible to create a code that will automatically saved an access database. For example, the database will be backup every week, like that. You dont have to manually back it up. Im using windows 7 by the way. :)

Comment: That is not something you should do with PHP. I am not sure if there is a `cron` program (a program that executes scheduled tasks) for Windows 7, but that would be the proper way of backing up a database periodically.

Answer (score 2):

**re: actually performing the backup**

Backing up a native Access database is simply a matter of copying the entire database file (.mdb for Access_2003 and earlier, .accdb for Access_2007 and later). You *could* use PHP for that, but any scripting language would work, even a simple Windows batch file that does something like

```
copy /Y d:\apps\databases\mydatabase.accdb z:\backups\databases\*.*
```

If you're really set on using PHP then you'll likely end up using the [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.

**re: automatic scheduling of the backup**

The Task Scheduler in Windows could take care of that for you. Once you've created your script to copy the database file(s) you can create a scheduled task to run it periodically. See the MSDN article [Using the Task Scheduler (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.