# Automatically backing up an Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

We have a Microsoft Access database saved on the network drive. What I am looking for is to be able to automatically backup these files on a daily or weekly basis. What is the best way to go about this? Can somebody please explain the procedure?

Answer (score 3):

*(borrowing heavily from one of my earlier answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15312534/2144390)...)*

**re: actually performing the backup**

Backing up a native Access database is simply a matter of copying the entire database file (`.mdb` for Access_2003 and earlier, `.accdb` for Access_2007 and later). You could use any scripting language you prefer, even a simple Windows batch file that does something like

```
copy /Y d:\apps\databases\mydatabase.accdb z:\backups\databases\*.*
```

**re: automatic scheduling of the backup**

The Task Scheduler in Windows could take care of that for you. Once you've created your script to copy the database file(s) you can create a scheduled task to run it periodically. See the MSDN article [Using the Task Scheduler (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.